# Converting a birthdate to its lunar year equivalent

Tags: java, jodatime

Is it possible to figure out someones lunar birth day given that you know the regular (gregorian) day?

There is an example on the joda time website that shows:

```
// setup date object for midday on May Day 2004 (ISO year 2004)
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2004, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);

// find out what the same instant is using the Islamic Chronology
DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
```

Is this ISO year representing the gregorian representation?

Answer (score 0):

The [ISO chronology](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) is an extended ([proleptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_calendar)) Gregorian calendar, meaning that strictly speaking, there was no Gregorian chronology before the Gregorian calendar was accepted in 1582, but the ISO chronology extends it before that. So yes, for all modern (post-1582) dates, the ISO year is the same as the Gregorian year.

As an alternative, there's the [`GJChronology`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/GJChronology.html), which automatically switches between Julian and Gregorian chronologies, depending on the actual date, and a [`DateTime` constructor that accepts the desired chronology as a parameter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20org.joda.time.Chronology%29).